Storing numpy arrays in PostgreSQL: BYTEA vs. ARRAY for large integer arrays
I'm aware that PostgreSQL supports storing arrays directly. Is it more effective to store large numpy arrays of integers using PostgreSQL's native ARRAY type compared to BYTEA? Specifically, my arrays have the shape (10, 4, 224, 224, 3).
I'm currently storing large numpy arrays in PostgreSQL using the BYTEA data type. However, this approach requires reshaping the numpy arrays after retrieval, which adds some overhead.

What results did you get when you tested both ways?
